# can I obtain a io.Writer from a http.ResponseWriter?

Tags: json, io, go, httpserver

I would like to use `json.Encoder` to write to a `http.ResponseWriter`.

I wonder, where do I get `http.ResponseWriter`'s own `io.Writer` ?

(`io.Writer` is required as parameter for `json.NewEncoder`)

any ideas?

Comment: "The trick" with Go interfaces is that neither a type is required to implement an interface explicitly nor do you have to somehow "extract" an interface from an instance of a particular type to use it.  Instead, the rule is simple: wherever some bit of code expects something implementing a particular interface, just pass there *any* value whose type implements *all the methods of the required interface* -- and all will happen automagically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`http.ResponseWriter`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) implements `Write([]byte) (int, error)`. Therefore you can use it everywhere where a [`io.Writer`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) is required.

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(w)
}
```

[Here](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) you can find some background information on how Go uses interfaces as a way to specify the behavior of an object.

Comment: Please note that this way you loose the ability to send any other http status code than 200. So even if the  encoding errors out you can't write a 400 or 500 code. That's because ``If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK).``

Comment: Is there a way to generically find all the interaces implemented by some interface(like http.ResponseWriter implements io.Writer)  ?